# How to change overlay whole div by an image via CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to figure out, how to have two divs that would react to `onmouseover` event. One should overlay with picture the other, whereas the bottom div should contain another image and other elements such as buttons, text etc. Could you please show me, how I need to adjust my code, to make it work?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">    
    <div id="bottom" >
        <img id="image" src="http://curiousanimals.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/cat-programmer.jpg"/>
        <p id="text">
            Hello World!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="top">
      <img  id="cat" src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container img {
  position:absolute;
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
#top img:hover {  
    opacity:0; 
}
#text{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:white;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    left:150px;
    top:350px;
}
```

This is what I've got so far. But I'd need to display the Hello world only when bottom image is displayed.. As well if I'd have some button there, to make it react only in those situations.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7XCD/733/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way if you just want clickable elements on the bottom element, would be to just switch the top and bottom layer. So you make your top layer (including button and text) transparent and lay it over the visible image.
On hover you just blend it in.
If you do it the other way around the top image is blocking the clickevents.
I put a little example together here:

http://jsfiddle.net/L7XCD/732/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">    
<div class="cat-image bottom">
  <img  class="cat" src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="cat-image top" >
    <img class="image" src="http://curiousanimals.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/cat-programmer.jpg"/>
    <p class="text">
        Hello World!
    </p>
    <button>Click meow!</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; 
}

.top:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#top {
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}

#bottom #text {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: oh...thank you so much! For me, as a back end developer, are these front end technologies a tough problem sometimes :)

Comment: Oh...but wait a minute... if I'd add there a button, I can't push it...these elements seem to be disabled

Comment: Could you update your fiddle as I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: What browser are you using - seems fine in OSX and Chrome.